# CF EF MVC multiple 1-to-1 foreign key from same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, code-first

I have this:

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MatchedUser1")]
    public string IdOf1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MatchedUser2")]
    public string IdOf2 { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User1")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser MatchedUser1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User2")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser MatchedUser2 { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUser> User1 { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> User2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to have a table (Match) containing 2 users as foreign keys.

When I try to add the migration the console replies:

> "The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'MatchedUser1' on type
>   'H4L.Web.Models.Match' is not valid. The property 'User1' is not a
>   valid navigation property on the related type
>   'H4L.Web.Models.ApplicationUser'. Ensure that the property exists and
>   is a valid reference or collection navigation property."

And I don't want to use fluent API unless it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.
I thought the code had to be done solely in this class but apparently I needed to add this in the ApplicationUser class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Match> User1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Match> User2 { get; set; }
```